# How to install themes in Android 4.1.2

Tags: themes

I have heard many applications from play store that install themes but didn't try them yet as i don't know its working .I want a new theme on My Samsung Galaxy trend Duos phone-GT-S7392 (Android 4.1.2).Do we have any themes that can be installed from Samsung ??

Comment: Themes for what? Android doesn't provide a way for end users to theme the whole device, but some apps are themeable (commonly launchers).

Comment: can you clearly explain what a launcher is and what do you mean by only some apps

Comment: I mean that it's possible for an app to be written so that you can add themes to it, but without rooting the device there's no way to make a theme that changes the appearance of all apps. A launcher is a home screen replacement app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung phones that are running TouchWiz (Samsung's fork of Android) do not support native themeing, as is the case with other manufacturers such as Sony and Acer. You can check if you're running TouchWiz by dialing `*#0*#` on your dialer - if a new screen appears, you are most definitely running TouchWiz.

To achieve support for the theme apps you see on the Play Store, you need to install or *flash* a custom Android ROM, such as CyanogenMod and ParanoidAndroid.